# Uniquify Arraylist of Arrays by their second element

Tags: java, arraylist, set, unique

Given an Arraylist like this:

```
List<Integer[]> list = new Arraylist<>();
list.add(new Integer[] {13, 1});
list.add(new Integer[] {100, 2});
list.add(new Integer[] {143, 2});
list.add(new Integer[] {185, 3});
list.add(new Integer[] {111, 3});
list.add(new Integer[] {98, 4});
```

how can I uniquify the list in respect to their second element with lowest value for the first element?

Usually, I would simply turn a list into a set an return it as a list again but how do I handle this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you always have 100 as the first element in each item of arraylist?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that first element in each array will be always 100? If not then what should be result for arrays `{200, 1}` and `{300, 1}`?

Comment: No it is not always 100. I would choose the smaller one in this case.

Comment: In that case use [edit] option and put that info in your question directly since it is important detail. Not everyone will be looking for it in comments section.

Comment: Already did that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an intermediate object

```
class Intermediate implements Comparable<Intermediate> {
    private Integer[] array;
    public Intermediate(Integer[] arr) { array = arr; }
    public boolean equals(Object o) { 
        return (o instanceof Intermediate) &&
            array[1] == ((Intermediate)o).array[1];
    }
    public int compareTo(Intermediate i) {
        return Integer.compare(array[0], i.array[0]);
    }
    public Integer[] toTarget() { return array; }
}
```

then create a stream from your list which maps to the intermediate

```
yourList.stream().map(Intermediate::new)
```

this is now a `Stream<Intermediate>`. The equals is defined on the second int, so you can use distinct, then map back to your array and collect.

```
    .sorted() // make sure to take the lowest first value
    .distinct()
    .map(Intermediate::toTarget)
    .collect(toList());
```

or, if you only want the first int from the arrays,

```
    .map(i -> i.toTarget()[0])
    .collect(toList());
```

(which would give you `[13, 100, 111, 98]` for your sample list).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution! I edited the task a bit. I'm sorry that I did not formulated it that way in the first place..

Comment: @A.Ka. I don't really see what's changed. Anyway, I updated my answer to include a mapping to only the first integer in the array if that's what you meant.

Comment: I, again, forgot to mention a important fact: The value of the first element should be minimal (finally edited the task completely). I am only interested in the second elements but they should be those that have the lowest first element.

Comment: @A.Ka. But that only means you need to sort the stream ascendingly by the first int. I put that in.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that's the best solution but you can still use a set for the found values and do it like that:

```
    Set<Integer> found=new HashSet<>();
    list.removeIf(p->!found.add(p[1]));
```

The idea is that you need to store the found values anyway. You can use a filter with the streams Api but it is harder to keep a state and you will probably still need to maintain another collection with the already added values. So I think it is an easy solution.

Thats if you have it as a given that first value is always 100. Otherwise you might need to rework it a bit ;)

Comment: Thanks! I edited the task a bit. How would it be if I wanted to store the entry with the lower first element?